# Best Overloaded Method Match Has Some Invalid Arguments Asp.net Wcf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am getting error "Best Overloaded Method Match Has Some Invalid Arguments"

my code is,

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsultantShares> consultantShareList = (Session["ProjectShare"] as List<ConsultantShares>);
        CIService.CIServiceClient client = new CIService.CIServiceClient();
        client.GetConsultantScoreAsync(consultantShareList,this.txtProjectId.Text,this.ddlWorkClass.SelectedValue);
        client.GetConsultantScoreCompleted += new EventHandler<CIService.GetConsultantScoreCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetConsultantScoreCompleted);
```

error list as,

```
Error   196 The best overloaded method match for
 'CIService.CIServiceClient.GetConsultantScoreAsync(InspectionServices.ConsultantShares[], string, string)'
 has some invalid arguments G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\Summary.aspx.cs  32  
9   G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\


Error   197 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<InspectionServices.ConsultantShares>' 
to 'InspectionServices.ConsultantShares[]'  G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\Summary.aspx.cs  32  
40  G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\
```

while i have the following,

in

```
namespace CIService

    {
        [GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public class CIServiceClient : ClientBase<ICIService>, ICIService
        {
               public void GetConsultantScoreAsync(ConsultantShares[] cs, string targetProjectId, string workclass);
        public void GetConsultantScoreAsync(ConsultantShares[] cs, string targetProjectId, string workclass, object userState);
        }
    }
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

EDITED:

Getting error on

```
Error   30  The type or namespace name 'InventoryProject' does not exist in the namespace 'CIService' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\ProjectDetails.aspx.cs   108 23  G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\
```

CIService.InventoryProject invProject = new CIService.InventoryProject();

while CIService

```
 public InventoryProject GetInventoryProjectDetail(string consultantId, string projectId)
        {
            ProjectService prjService = new ProjectService();
            return prjService.GetInventoryProjectDetail(consultantId, projectId);
        }

 public List<InventoryProject> GetProjectsByConsultant(string consultantId, int currentPageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            ProjectService prjService = new ProjectService();
            return prjService.GetProjectsByConsultant(consultantId, currentPageNumber, pageSize);
        }
```

while CIService is my WCF service and InventoryProject.datasource is some other project of databasemanager whose dll is using in this wcf project but why it is not recognizsing "inventoryproject"

Hopes for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First you can call `.ToList()` on your array before passing to method as parameter, Second option is you can define the default collection type while creating the proxy (Adding service reference).

[image]

The reason you are getting the error is because, When you added the service reference you probably specified, `System.Collection.Generic.List` as the Collection type. You can modify that to Array.

Comment: one more thing i wanna ask that i am getting error same like it

Comment: @testerJoe, make sure your web methods are accepting parameters in a same type, either list or array. It would be simpler for you to handle that through proxy

Comment: i am editing post with the error like it yup i am using parameter in a same type

Comment: @testerJoe, if you have reference to your project, in your web service as well as other project, then make sure you have checked `Reuse types in referenced assemblies`. Its available in the same screen. This will let both project use the same assemblies.

Comment: i checked Reuse types in referenced assemblies as shown in image above instead i am getting this error on more thing i wanna tell you some times it shows me this error and some times it do not when i check InventoryProject.databases it is like this,

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--

-->
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="InventoryProject" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
   <TypeInfo>DataAccessManager.InventoryProject, DataAccessManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>

Comment: Generic object datasource not declared  ?? :( may be it is causing issue

Comment: @testerJoe, it looks like unrelated to the current problem in the question. I am not sure what is going on here, You can investigate it yourself first and see if you can determine what is going on, and later you can post a new question *(if the problem is unrelated)*

Comment: @ habib i searched alot but havent found solution would you check my project via team viewer ?Will be Thankfull for your this kind of act